# Median Filter with cyclic padding in Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

```
%This routine performs median filtering on an image.
% 
% Input:       im - a grayscale image (values in [0,255]) 
%    winSize - a 1x2 vector describing the size (height,width) of thefiltering window. 
% Output:     nim - a grayscale image (values in [0,255]) which is the median filtered im.   
%             Image nim is of the same size as im.
% 
% Method:  Performs Median Filtering on image im in windows of size winSize. Assume the 
%                     window origin is at floor(size(B)/2)+1. Assume cyclic-padding.
```

so here is the definition of the exercise i was given in image processing
and here is my solution:

```
function [ nim ] = medianFilt( im,winSize )
nim = im;
temp = cat(2,[im ;im(1:winSize(1)-1,:)],[ im(:,1:winSize(2)-1); im(1:winSize(1)-1,1:winSize(2)-1)])

for i = 1:size(im,1);
    for j = 1:size(im,2);
        winSizeMatrix = temp(i:i+winSize(1)-1,j:j+winSize(2)-1);
        winSizeVector = reshape(winSizeMatrix,[],1);
        medianOfVector = median(double(winSizeVector));
        nim(i,j) = medianOfVector;
    end
end

end
```

i get a result with a smooth picture - i'm using salt and pepper filter , but the last pixels look like they are copied from the first pixels and not as much as a fixing filter. is that they way my output should be ? or am I missing something?

also can someone please explain why do i need to assume that the window origin is at floor(size(im/2)+1)??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function [ nim ] = medianFilt( im,winSize )
%This routine performs median filtering on an image.
% 
% Input:       im - a grayscale image (values in [0,255]) 
%                       winSize - a 1x2 vector describing the size (height,width) of the filtering window. 
% Output:     nim - a grayscale image (values in [0,255]) which is the median filtered im. 
%                       Image nim is of the same size as im.
% 
% Method:  Performs Median Filtering on image im in windows of size winSize. Assume the 
%                     window origin is at floor(size(B)/2)+1. Assume cyclic-padding.
nim = im;
%temp = cat(2,[im ;im(1:winSize(1)-1,:)],[ im(:,1:winSize(2)-1);     im(1:winSize(1)-1,1:winSize(2)-1)]);
paddedIm = padarray(im, [floor(winSize(1)/2) floor(winSize(2)/2)],'circular');

for i = 1:size(im,1);
    for j = 1:size(im,2);
        startAi = i; % start point of window in padded array A to convolve with mask
        finishAi = i + winSize(1) - 1; % start point of  window in padded array A to convolve with mask
        startAj = j; %end point of window in padded array A to convolve with mask
        finishAj = j + winSize(2) - 1; %end point of window in padded array A to convolve with mask
        % create vector out of the window to multiply with vector of mask
        vectPaddedA = reshape(paddedIm(startAi :finishAi,startAj:finishAj)',1,[]);
        medianOfVector = median(double(vectPaddedA));
        nim(i,j) = medianOfVector;
    end
end

end
```

here is my solution for your problem. 
you had a misunderstanding the center of the mask is in floor(size(mask,1)/2), you have calculated it as in the top left corner (1,1).

therefore the padding needs to be cyclic all around the image and not just in the lower and right edges.

Answer (score 0):

Your padding is wrong - you only added padding at the end of the image (both axis), but not in the beginning.

Window origin means where to put the output of the filter in each step. If it's not in the window center, the whole output image will be shifted. In this case it's not very important, but in more complicated methods it can produce different outputs.

Comment: why do i need padding in the beginning? i'm going from top left to the bottom right corner.

Comment: To calculate the median for the first (top-left) pixel in the image, you need a window around it. Since the pixel is at the borders of the image, the value of pixels in the window is undefined. You must assume what the values are. In your case: cyclic padding. Other options are to assume the values equal to zero, or equal to the nearest valid pixel

Comment: i still don't understand what is wrong with my code. i surrounded my image :    temp = cat(2,[im ;im(1:winSize(1)-1,:)],[ im(:,1:winSize(2)-1); im(1:winSize(1)-1,1:winSize(2)-1)])

Comment: Run your code on this image:

im = [1 2 3 ; 4 5 6 ; 7 8 9]

winSize=[2 2]

As you can see, the image is not fully padded